# Run JavaScript in Sublime Text

Tags: javascript

I have searched and found a way to make JavaScript works on SublimeText. The way is like that in steps:

- Sublime Text > File > New File > Type:
  console.log("Hello World");
- Press Ctrl + S (Save) > script.js
- Install Node.js
- Sublime Text > Tools > Build System > New Build System > Type:

```js
    {
     "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
     "selector": "source.js"
    }
```

- Save As Node.sublime-build
- Sublime Text > Tools > Build System > Node

That worked well and I can get the console results well
Now how can I use or refer to the index.html file?
To be more specific I have two files: index.html and script.js and I need to run the JS on sublime text but I got
`ReferenceError: document is not defined` on such a line

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
```

Comment: There is no `document` object in Node.js since it's only available in browser runtimes.

Comment: Why don't you simply write your file like `script.js` then execute it in a terminal with `node script.js`? Also, not sure what you're trying to do, because Node is a server-side technology, there is no DOM, no elements by ID to select.

Comment: `I need to run the JS on sublime text` Why do you need to run Javascript from within a text editor? Text editors are meant to edit text, not to run javascript. Why don't you just drop your HTML file in a browser?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replies. The idea is to have all in one container. I mean to have the index.html and the script.js in one folder and use the Sublime Text as IDE :)

Answer (score 2):

[document object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document). relates to the DOM(Document Object Model) in the Web Browsers. `Node.js` is desktop `JavaScript` runtime environment, It'll not give to access to DOM objects.

If you want to access the document, object in Node.js you can use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a beginner at I am lost in fact in the link that is related browerify. Can you guide me how to use it in my case?

Comment: Browserify (like Webpack) is for browser development, not Node.js.